# How do I get css syntax highlighting while editing a php file?

Tags: php, css, vim, heredoc

How do I setup my .vimrc to have syntax highlighting for a region of PHP code that contains css?

Example:

```
<?php

$string = <<<css
a { color:blue; background:white;}
css;
```

Is there a vim plugin or do I need to update my .vimrc?

Comment: see http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6867/highlight-heredoc-as-perl-code